# Can someone tell me that what does that mean in Bootstrap(vividly)

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
```

I tried in bootstrap but i can't understand that mean.

Answer (score 3):

> In Bootstrap, the "row" class is used mainly to hold columns in it.
> Bootstrap divides each row into a grid of 12 virtual columns. In the
> following example, the col-md-6 div will have the width of 6.

So, class=`col-md-8` means: When the window width is less than 768px, this `<div>` will occupy 8/12

And for `<div class="col-6 col-md-4">`, means when window width less than 576px, this `<div>` will occupy 6/12 and when it less than 768px, will occupy 4/12.

You can see the detail in [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

[image]